# how to simplify including substring check

Tags: ruby

Now,I need to write the logic in

```
if STR.include? "week" or STR.include? "precourse" or STR.include? "hi"
 do somthing
end
```

Is there any more elegant way?

Answer (score 2):

You could eliminate repetition of the inclusion check by putting the tokens into an array and using [reduce](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) to accumulate whether any of them can be found within `STR`:

```
tokens = ['week', 'precourse', 'hi']
do_thing if tokens.reduce(false) {|y, v| y || STR.include?(v) }
```

*explanation:*

```
do_thing if tokens.reduce(false) {|y, v| y || STR.include?(v) }
^                         ^        ^  ^  ^
a                         b        c  d  e
```

- **a.** call a method (*"do somthing"*) ***if*** the reduction evaluates true
- **b.** provide reduce with an initial value to seed the result; we start with `false`
- **c.** call the accumulator value `y`; it collects the result of each inclusion check
- **d.** call the array item value `v`; it is the token we pass to `include?`
- **e.** logically `OR` the accumulated value against the result of calling `STR.include?` on the current token

Comment: Ahh, yes. ruby's notorious inject() hiding behind another name (Or is it reduce hiding behind ruby's notorious inject?). Nice creativity.  Note that the op's original code also short circuits, and in some cursory benchmarks op's original code can be almost 3 times as fast as reduce/inject depending on data.  inject was significantly faster than regex alternation with all data I tested.  The longer the strings got and the deeper into the string a match is found, the closer include? and inject got in times(~ equivalent) and trounced regex alternation(by a factor of 6).

Answer (score 0):

What language is it in?

IMHO an if statement with a few arguments might be the only way.

What I would do in java.

```
String something = "Pizza Pie";

if (something.contains("Pizza") || something.contains("Pie")) {
    System.out.println("Yarp");
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged as Ruby.

Comment: Gotcha,  must have missed that party.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any more elegant way?

Yes, but it depends on what is in your `str` variable.

1. Because you are using `include?` instead of `==`, this probably won't work for you:

   ```
   if ['week', 'precourse', 'hi'].include? str
   ```

   `str` would have to be exactly one of those items in the array.
2. But you can do the following if `str` is longer than the items in the array:

   ```
   if str.match /week|precourse|hi/
   ```
3. To avoid hardcoding those strings in your regex, you can get a little trickier:

   ```
   target_strs = %w{ week precourse hi }
   p target_strs  #=> ["week", "precourse", "hi"]

   str = "Hello and hi"

   if str[ Regexp.union(target_strs) ]  #=> str[ /week|precourse|hi/ ]
     puts 'yes'
   end

   --output:--
   ["week", "precourse", "hi"]
   yes
   ```

   See the docs for String#[] when you use a regex: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D
4. There is nothing wrong with the way you did it, and it's easier to read. :)